AWS WAF Access from a specific country
I configured a rule in AWS WAF/ELB to allow access only from Brazil, but some IPs (example below) from other countries appear in the access.log and error.log of the EC2 instance (ubuntu + nginx). Does anyone know why this happens?
Example the error.log:
2024/06/13 13:07:38 [error] 12646#12646: *20792 open() "/var/www/html/.env" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 185.254.196.173, server: www.xxxx.com, request: "GET /.env HTTP/1.1", host: "44.214.43.2"

The client IP is from "Ukraine".
Rule JSON:
{
  "Name": "XXXX-OnlyIPsBR",
  "Priority": 0,
  "Statement": {
    "NotStatement": {
      "Statement": {
        "GeoMatchStatement": {
          "CountryCodes": [
            "BR"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Action": {
    "Block": {}
  },
  "VisibilityConfig": {
    "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
    "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
    "MetricName": "XXXX-OnlyIPsBR"
  }
}

What's wrong with the rule?
